# Orchard - Edit 'Widget' from homepage website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Looking through the introduction tutorials for Orchard:

```
http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=orchard-fundamentals&highlight=kevin-kuebler_introduction-to-orchard*1,2!kevin-kuebler_shape-of-orchard!kevin-kuebler_modules-and-content*1,8,4!kevin-kuebler_themes-and-widgets*9!kevin-kuebler_blogs-and-users#introduction-to-orchard
```

In the videos, he can edit the widgets and pages from the actual home page, with a dotted line round the widgets for example with an 'edit' appearing at the top right of each widget.  From here if he clicks it will navigate him to the Admin/Widget section of the site, which I know how to get to....

My Question being how can I enable the options to edit the widgets from the home page of the website without having to navigate to it on the admin site?

Thanks

The edit buttons can be seen from the below image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is disabled by default - you can turn it on in Dashboard. It's called `Widget Control Wrapper`. You need to enable `Content Control Wrapper` feature as well.

Comment: Also needed to enable the content control wrapper...thanks for answer